# Cordova + Crosswalk iOS still using UIWebView

Tags: ios, cordova, uiwebview, wkwebview, crosswalk

I didn't find a lot of instruction setting up crosswalk for iOS it seems like it should be as simple as:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview
cordova build ios
```

Because I've had issues with plugins not taking effect before I do the following:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview
cordova platform remove ios
cordova platform add ios
cordova build ios
```

After having done this, when I capture the view hierarchy and inspecting that it's still using "UIWebView" which has a "UIWebBrowserView" inside of it (which is inside of a scroll view and there are a couple image views too).

Also, navigator.userAgent is as follows:

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/13B143 (5618403776)" = $1
```

Another test someone mentioned was essentially:

```
if (window.indexedDB)
    console.log('Using crosswalk');
else
    console.log('Not using crosswalk/wkwebview');
```

And window.indexedDB is undefined.

So...  what do I need to do so that the app uses wkwebview?

Comment: Somebody voted to close this because it's asking to find a "tool"; and as a result answers are biased.  My original intent was not to ask for a tool to be found, I thought "Crosswalk"'s cordova plugin would you know... work on more platforms than just Android cause that's the point of crosswalk.

Anyway, I think the answers have not been subjective, and are helpful to those whom may read this looking for answers similar to mine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### How I solved the issue

As JesseMonroy so helpfully answered(feel free to upvote him) the **cordova crosswalk plugin is only for android**.

Because of apple's terms of service, **crosswalk for iOS uses wkwebview instead** of what non-ios version of chrome would use.

Since there is no cordova plugin I know of for crosswalk iOS, **I found plugins for WKWebView**

**The plugin I used was:**
https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/WKWebView

This is probably **a better option**:  https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine.. But **it errored for me**.

---

#### <s>Coming soon:</s>

As stated by Honry:

> Crosswalk will soon provide a cordova plugin for Crosswalk ios, see
>   ticket https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-4911

XWalk will not be supporting an iOS plugin afterall because it does not provide any must have advantages over wkwebview

Comment: I also tried to find a Crosswalk iOS cordova plugin and finally gave up and used cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine, which worked well for me.

Answer (score 13):

A review of the [plugin repository](http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?q=) does NOT indicate a [cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview](http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?q=crosswalk-web) that supports iOS. This means crosswalk does not work as a *plugin* for iOS.

Yes there is support for [Crosswalk for iOS](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/ios.html), but you must install via the github repository or other means.

- Cordova [Embedding WebViews](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.4.0/guide/hybrid/webviews/index.html)

FWIW: there is a [WkWebview](http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?q=wkwebview) plugin

**UPDATE:** 2016-03-19. The follow post was made on February 16, 2016:
[Plugins From Git Repositories Are Now Available on PhoneGap Build!](http://phonegap.com/blog/2016/02/16/git-plugins/)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  
I +1'd your answer but I will probably write an answer with instructions on how to incorportate crosswalk for ios with cordova once I figure that out.  (Or if you appended that sort of instructions I would accept your answer).  Regardless your information was very helpful and appreciated

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for the offer. My plate is full. If you write an answer, I will get it out to [the bloggers](http://codesnippets.altervista.org/documentation/phonegap/bookmarks/topBloggers.html).

Answer (score 2):

Crosswalk will soon provide a cordova plugin for Crosswalk ios, see ticket https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-4911

Comment: That is good, thanks for the post.  I'll look forward to using this plugin when it becomes available.

Comment: Looks like it won't happen: "we are not going to implement it, as Crosswalk iOS XWalkView does not provide more feature than the system WKWebView when it is used as a Cordova plugin webview."

Comment: @user276648 where did you quote that from ?

Comment: @Vince: it's one of the comments of the ticket.

Comment: They closed it as "won´t fix" :/

Comment: Crosswalk will have no more releases: https://crosswalk-project.org/blog/crosswalk-final-release.html