# phonegap-app-developer does not work with cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine

Tags: ios, cordova, wkwebview

can anyone run phonegap-app-developer with cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine?

this is my environment:

```
phonegap: 6.3.0
cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine: 1.0.3
cordova-labs-local-webserver: from https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugins.git#master:local-webserver
```

I use webpack dev server to download assets, and I think I configure it  to return CORS header already (Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *).

under such a circumstance, I try to run phonegap-app-developer with cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine. for the first time with this [instruction](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine). but got following error, which seems to described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24882834/wkwebview-not-loading-local-files-under-ios-8/).

```
2016-08-16 16:50:01.026 PhoneGap[456:87484] Copying Cordova Assets
2016-08-16 16:50:01.026 PhoneGap[456:87484] Found /www folder. Will copy Cordova assets to it.
Received an unexpected URL from the web process: 'file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/...snip.../Library/NoCloud/phonegapdevapp/www/index.html'
Received an invalid message "WebPageProxy.DecidePolicyForNavigationAction" from the web process.
```

then I find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36477450/even-basic-ionic-project-with-cordova-wkwebview-engine-plugin-produces-white-scr) article, do the same with phonegap command (instead of ionic). as a result, above error is gone. but still phonegap-app-developer shows white screen.

official [repository](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-developer) still does not use wkwebview plugin, so I doubt it does not work with developer app.